# Trocando de mysql para mysqli

Tags: mysql

Fala pessoa beleza?
Então eu estou a mais ou menos 3 dias fuçando e mexendo neste código.
Todos os erros de obsolencia do mysql somem, e eu consigo navegar normalmente pela área de administrador.
Porém, ao sair da área e tentar entra novamente, ele me alerta com 'Acesso Negado'
Ou seja, nessa brincadeira de alterar bugou alguma coisa que fez com que o sistema não aceitasse meu login...
Estou a horas tentando arrumar e nada, alguém pode dar uma lida nos arquivos e ver se acha algo?
Abraços.

Principal.php:

```
$usuario_id   = $_SESSION['usuario_id'];
$usuario_nome = $_SESSION['usuario_nome'];
}
?>
<?php
// PEGA OS DADOS DO USUÁRIO

$query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_usuarios where id = '$usuario_id'";
    $resultado = mysqli_query ($conexao, $query);
$campo = mysqli_fetch_array ($resultado);   
$usuario_nome = $campo ['nome'];  

$sign = "ike3da";
?>


<html>
<head>
<META http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<title>Área Administrativa</title>
</head>
<style type="text/css">
body { width: 100%; margin:0; padding:0; background-color:#000; text-align:center; background: url(imags/bg-topo.png) center top no-repeat; font: 12px tahoma; color:#FFF; }
#topo-2 { margin: 0 auto; height: 260px; }
#banner { margin: 0 auto; width: 410px; height: 253px; background-image:url(imags/logo.png);}
/* ------------- */
#bemvindo { margin: 0 auto; margin-top: 10px; width: 300px; height: 40px; background: url(imags/bg-png.png) repeat; }
#menuadmin { margin: 0 auto; width: 100%; height: 45px; margin-top: 20px; background: url(imags/bg-png.png) repeat;}
#menuzin { margin: auto; width: 820px; margin-right: 10px; margin-top: 10px;}
ul.menuadmin2 { text-align: center; margin-top: 10px; margin-right:100px;}
ul.menuadmin2 li { padding: 0 50px 0 20px; display: inline;}
ul.menuadmin2 li a { text-decoration: none; font: bold 12px Tahoma, Arial; color:#d4d4d4; }
ul.menuadmin2 li a:hover { text-decoration: none; font: bold 12px Tahoma, Arial; color:#d5872d; }
/*---------------*/
#sistems { width: 80%; margin: 0 auto; margin-top: 10px; background:url(imags/bg-png.png) repeat; } 
#baixo { width: 100%; height: 100px; margin-top: 40px; }
#baixo a { text-decoration:none; color:#CCC; }
#baixo a:hover { text-decoration:none; color:#F90; }
#baixo a:visited { text-decoration:none; color:#BBB; }
#quadro { margin:0 auto; width: 350px; background-color:#050505; border:#070707 1px solid; }
</style>
<body>
<div id="body2">
<div id="topo-2">
<div id="banner"></div>
</div>
<div id="bemvindo">
<div style="height:10px;"></div>
<span style="font: 15px tahoma; ">Seja bem-vindo, <b><?php echo "$usuario_nome"; ?></b>.</span>
</div>

<div id="menuadmin">

<div style="height:5px;"></div>
<ul class="menuadmin2">
             <li><a href="?pg=noticias_cadastrar">Cadastrar Not&iacute;cia</a></li>
                <li><a href="?pg=noticias_listar">Listar Not&iacute;cias</a></li>
                <li><a href="logout.php">Sair</a></li>   
            </ul>   

</div>

<div id="sistems">
<?php include "pages.php"; ?>
</div>
<div id="baixo">
<div id="quadro">
<div style="height:10px;"></div>
<div style="height:10px;"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

conexao.php:

```
    <?php
$conexao = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'wamp', 'noticias');
if($conexao){
      if (mysqli_select_db($conexao, 'noticias')){ print "";
      }else{ print "Não foi possível selecionar o Banco de Dados"; }
}else{ print "Erro ao conectar o MySQL"; }
?>
```

autenticacao.rotinas.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
include ("../config/conexao.php");


$cliente_username = $_POST["usuario"];
$cliente_password = $_POST["senha"];
$enviado          = $_POST["enviado"];

if ($enviado == "posted"){    

if (!isset($cliente_username) or !isset($cliente_password)) { echo "Erro!"; exit; }  
if (empty($cliente_username) or empty($cliente_password)) { echo "Dados inválidos!"; exit; }

$query = "select * from tbl_usuarios where login = '$cliente_username' and senha = '$cliente_password'";
$result = mysqli_query($conexao, $query);
$number = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if ($number==0) { ?><script>alert('Dados incorretos! Tente novamente.');history.back();</script>
<?php
exit;
} else {
$_SESSION['usuario_id'] = mysql_result($result,0,'id');
$_SESSION['usuario_nome'] = mysql_result($result,0,'nome');
?><script>document.location = '../principal.php'</script><?php
}
mysqli_close($conexao); 

} 
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema deve estar na criação das *sessions*, que ainda está usando `mysql_result`:

```
$_SESSION['usuario_id'] = mysql_result($result,0,'id');
$_SESSION['usuario_nome'] = mysql_result($result,0,'nome');
```

Mas não existe uma função `mysql_result` equivalente em `mysqli`, tem que usar as funções `mysqli_fetch_*` da classe [mysqli_result](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php).

A função `mysqli_fetch_assoc` retorna uma linha como um array associativo. Portanto, podes fazer assim:

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$_SESSION['usuario_id'] = $row['id'];
$_SESSION['usuario_nome'] = $row['nome'];
```

Comment: Simplesmente perfeito! Quebrou um galho irmão! Você é demais!!

Comment: Você pode aceitar esta resposta. [Como e por que aceitar uma resposta?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta)