# Mudando o mysql_result para mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Eu estou com um problema no código que meu professor passou, eu gostaria de mudar para `mysqli`, mas não consegui o `mysql_result`. Aqui está o código que ele me passou, se alguém puder me ajudar, agradeço.

```
 <?php
 //CONECTA COM O BANCO DE DADOS
 require_once("conecta.php");
 $usuario = $_POST['nome'];
 $senha = $_POST['senha'];
 $sql   =   mysql_query("SELECT A.apelido_cliente, A.nome_cliente, A.email_cliente FROM tbl_cliente A WHERE A.apelido_cliente  =  '$usuario' AND A.senha   =  '$senha'") or die("ERRO NO COMANDO SQL");
 //LINHAS AFETADAS PELA CONSULTA
 $row   =  mysql_num_rows($sql);
 //VERIFICA SE RETORNOU ALGO
 if($row == 0){
   echo "Usuário/Senha inválidos";
   echo "<br><a href='login.php'>Voltar</a>";
 } else {
     //PEGA OS DADOS
     $id   =   mysql_result($sql, 0, "cod_cliente");
     $nome =   mysql_result($sql, 0, "nome_cliente");
     $email =   mysql_result($sql, 0, "email_cliente");
     //INICIALIZA A SESS�O
     session_start();
     //GRAVA AS VARI�VEIS NA SESS�O
     $_SESSION["id"]    =   $id;
     $_SESSION["nome"]  =   $nome;
     $_SESSION["email"]  =   $email;
     //REDIRECIONA PARA A P�GINA QUE VAI EXIBIR OS PRODUTOS
     Header("Location: menu.php");
 }
?>
```

Comment: qual tipo de problema voce esta tendo com o msqli? jan tentou dar uma olhada no manual? http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.mysqli.php

Comment: [Trocando de mysql para mysqli](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/51077/91)

Comment: rray como mensionado no conteudo, minha dificuldade está no `mysql_result` que teria a função de armazenar o dado recebido para uma variável, já procurei em vários foruns para ver se tem algo equivalente no `mysqli`, mas de nada achei. Na possível "duplicata" ele quer saber mudar todo o código, no meu quero saber mudar `mysql_result`, eu apenas pus o código `mysql`, do jeito que me mostraram